# The keyword "price" for adwords?

Tags: seo, keywords, google-ads

I have a keyword that I use in adwords. In my local language which is translated as "caliper prices", has "landing page quality: under average"

Landing page of this URL is a list of calipers and prices, which is completely related with the keyword, however "caliper price" is not much existing on the page, It is hard to use that word more than once in the page. So any ideas to increase my adwords quality point for a keyword like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Few Methods to Increase Your Google Adwords Quality Points**

To increase your Quality Points in Adwords you need to make sure Google thinks you're quality is relevant to the keywords you are targeting, bad quality points is normally as a result of bad SEO. There are many ways to increase your quality points and here is a few methods how.

1. **Meta Title** - Use the keywords in a good sentence that you want to target in the title tag (Page Title)
2. **Meta Description** - Use the keywords in a good sentence in the meta description at least once.
3. **Alt Tags** - You can even use the keywords in the img alt tags, but don't repeat them otherwise this can be negative seo. I recommend at least once. Having 10-15 word sentences in alt tags is ok.
4. **Header Tags** - You should try and use the keyword at least once in a header tag - even it it means make an additional h2, h3, h4, h5 etc.
5. **Text Content** - Ensure that you use the keyword at least once in the text, repeating it twice is ok but no need to spam it there after.
6. **Internal Links** - If you have a menu on the page or aside sidebar then you can always hot link it some how on the side that gives a little more weight. but this step is optional I'd say.

Basically a low score means that Google considers the keyword you are trying to bid on not as relevant and you will be expected to BID higher if this is the case, you mention that you only have the keyword once well sadly that's not good enough in Googles eyes.

I understand your bidding on a translation word but then again Google considers separate keywords. And the only way to possibly score for both is to have both keywords on the page more times than you'd like or perhaps create and additional page with all translated keyword and then another on another page with non translated. Sorry I know this is probly not what you wanted to hear but Google does this for a reason, Money! and quality insurances, they can't get everything right.